$\lambda^k(\partial C)=0$ for all convex subsets $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ (reference request)
Where can I find a proof of the following theorem?

Theorem: If $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ is a convex set then $\lambda^k(\partial C)=0$.

Here $\lambda^k$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}^k$.
I only found a reference in German ("Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie" by Gänssler and Stute), however I'd like a reference written in English.

Maybe this one would suffice: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01202504?
